# xpath and extracting multiple values

Tags: php, dom, xpath

In my continuing saga of xpath and and extracting data I continue to struggle. I need just two values contained in a table cell. I can get to each individually, but I cannot access the other while there. I have cell's like so

```
<TR>
<TD width="120" align="center" valign="top">
<A href="http://www..yadayada.com"> <!--the href I need to extract-->
<IMG src="http://images.com/items/yada.gif" width="80" height="80" border="1"></A>
<BR>
<B>Random number PT</B><!--the text I need to extract-->
</TD>
```

I traverse like so:

```
@$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $rawPage );
@$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
@$queryResult = $xpath->query( "..../tr/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]/b" );
```

to get to the href link and similary,

```
@$queryResult = $xpath->query( "..../tr/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]/a" );
```

to get the text I need. And then I extract like so

```
//for the text in b
foreach ( $queryResult as $result )
{
echo $result->textContent . " text content<br>";
}
```

and for the link

```
//for the text in href
foreach ( $queryResult as $result )
{
echo $result->getAttribute( 'href' ) . " href<br>";
}
```

I do not pull each TD in the table and that's why I match `/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]` ones that have PT in the . I've read about unions and using `/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]/*[self::a or self::b` but my for each errors with `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

I've tried using nextSibling and all that too and it just is blank when I echo it. So, how can I get the two values out of my tables?

Comment: In `..../tr/td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]/b` what is `PT` ? your html does not have any word `PT`.

Comment: @VamanKulkarni, I have corrected that in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
//td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]
```

And

```
//td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]/a
```

Two queries should work,
Using your existing code

```
queryResult = $xpath->query( "//td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]" );
foreach ( $queryResult as $result )
{
  echo $result->textContent . " text content<br>";
}

$queryResult = $xpath->query( "//td[contains( b, 'PT' ) ]/a" );
foreach ( $queryResult as $result )
{
  echo $result->getAttribute( 'href' ) . " href<br>";
}
```

Comment: I have did this, as part of the single xpath query, however, I don't know how to implement this. do I write two separate xpath queries?

Comment: The way you describe it, it posts the b and a separate. I simply moved the href loop inside the first in order to post the matching href with the corresponding b. Thanks